# Bilinear objective function

Tags: discrete-optimization, binary-programming

I have an objective function containing the following

$$\pmb{\hat{C}_3(y)}= \sum_j \sum_{b} \sum_{w}  \bigg[ d_{bj} \tau_{wbj} \bigg( y_{wbj1}\ \ (1-p(w))  +  y_{wbj2} \sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') \ \ y_{{w'}bj1} \bigg) \bigg]$$

where $y \in \{0,1\}$. The rest are parameters. All the constraints that I have are linear.

Is there any way to relax this nonlinear problem other than introducing a new variable like $z = y \cdot y$? I am using LINGO to solve this problem and not even able to get a lower bound after many hours of running LINGO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this without adding new decision variables. But, I think that's your best bet, or worth a shot anyway. Something like:

$$z_{ww'bj} = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if }y_{wbj2} = y_{w'bj1} = 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

(I wasn't quite sure what the 1 and 2 at the end of the subscripts were so I basically ignored them.)

Then add constraints:
$$\begin{align*}
z_{ww'bj} & \ge y_{wbj2} + y_{w'bj1} - 1 \\
z_{ww'bj} & \le y_{wbj2} \\
z_{ww'bj} & \le y_{w'bj1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for something different than this method. What about Lagrangian relaxation? I am not sure how to use it here as I have no background on it. Do you recommend any reference?

Comment: My favorite overview of Lagrangian relaxation is [this one](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.1040.0263). I'm not sure LR is going to help you a lot here, because you still need to be able to solve a problem with the bilinear terms, but maybe you can make it work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Note that the $z$ variables do not need to be declared binary. They can be declared real-valued; the constraints will force them to be binary.

Comment: Introducing the $z$ variables made the problem very large in terms of the number of variables. Any other suggestions, please.

Comment: Search term: "compact linearization"